# InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I first tried to install tensorflow=2.4.0 in Conda with the channel defaults, but it caused an error:

```
conda install tensorflow=2.4.0
```

**Error:**

```
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - tensorflow=2.4.0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Then I'm tried using the Conda Forge channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=2.4.0
```

**Error:**

```
Solving environment: failed
InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install using an older version of conda.  There is a similar issue posted here: https://github.com/facebookresearch/vissl/issues/198

Try to update conda to 4.9.2 or higher using:

```
conda update conda -n base -y
```

---

If you don't have permission to update your conda version, you can always create a new environment with conda in it, and use **that** environment to install the package.

```
(base)$ conda create -n conda_env python conda==4.9.2
(base)$ conda activate conda_env
(conda_env)$ conda install tensorflow==2.4.0 -n my_other_env
```

You should check that your `conda_env` is picking up whichever config options you have as well.

Comment: conda version is 4.4.10 and I don't have permissions to update it