# InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec =2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conda

I tried to create a certain environment in Conda (v.5.3.0) but instead got the
[following result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WB4U.png)

As can be seen in the screenshot I tried creating new environment, after some tips from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888763/invalidversionspecerror-invalid-version-spec-2-7), but it only got me more confused than before.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

UPD: I have updated conda to the latest version (23.3.1), but it caused a new error instead. Now there are conflicts because of incompatible packages.
Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhhvG.png).

Comment: What is your conda version?

Comment: Conda version is 4.5.11

Comment: Can you try `conda update conda`?

Comment: The original question here was answered (i.e., update `conda`) and is covered by duplicate marking. If you want the follow up question addressed, please create a new question and [refrain from posting screenshots of shell sessions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidVersionSpecError: Invalid version spec: =2.7` issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10618) and a possible fix is [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10618#issuecomment-844841067).

Also, `conda create -n conda_env python==4.9.2` failed because there is no version `4.9.2`. At the time this answer is written the latest python version is `3.11.4`.

Comment: Please don't post a link as the only answer to the question. Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @FlyingTeller This question is not easily reproducible and copy/pasting all the possible answers and solutions from a github issue that can be easily be searched is not really an answer. Also, there is an edit button for fixing the answer. This is not a constructive comment at all. Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work